# Modify GetFeatureInfo request from WMS with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have a map built with leaflet. There are three basemaps. The first one is a basic OSM map. The second and third one ('Boundaries' and 'FNP') are WMS. I want to show attributes by GetFeatureInfo from the WMS 'FNP', but just want to request the values of the columns 'GEMEINDE', 'NUTZUNG' and 'STAND'. Here is the code for this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
 
 <title>FNP</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q==" crossorigin=""></script>
 
 <script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/WCXTfKrGxLNzfpUe-D2TgHwMpm4.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <style>
 
  html, body {
   height: 100%
  }
  
  #mapid {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 800px;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
   #mapid{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
   }
  }
 </style>
 
</head>
<body>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js"></script>

 <div id="mapid"></div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 <!-- *********************** betterWms ************************************ -->
 
 L.TileLayer.BetterWMS = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({
  
  onAdd: function (map) {
   // Triggered when the layer is added to a map.
   //   Register a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
   L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
   map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },
   
  onRemove: function (map) {
   // Triggered when the layer is removed from a map.
   //   Unregister a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
   L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
   map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },
   
  getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
   // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
   var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
    showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
    showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
     },
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    showResults(error);  
     }
   });
  },
   
  getFeatureInfoUrl: function (latlng) {
   // Construct a GetFeatureInfo request URL given a point
   var point = this._map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, this._map.getZoom()),
    size = this._map.getSize(),
    
    params = {
      request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
      service: 'WMS',
      srs: 'EPSG:4326',
      styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
      transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
      version: this.wmsParams.version,      
      format: this.wmsParams.format,
      bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
      height: size.y,
      width: size.x,
      layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
      query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
      info_format: 'text/html',
      propertyName: 'GEMEINDE,NUTZUNG,STAND'
    };
  
   params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'i' : 'x'] = point.x;
   params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'j' : 'y'] = point.y;
   
   return this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url, true);
  },
   
  showGetFeatureInfo: function (err, latlng, content) {
   if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // do nothing if there's an error
   
   // Otherwise show the content in a popup, or something.
   L.popup({ maxWidth: 800})
     .setLatLng(latlng)
     .setContent(content)
     .openOn(this._map);
    }
 });

 L.tileLayer.betterWms = function (url, options) {
   return new L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url, options);  
 };
 
 <!-- *****************map******************************** -->
 
 var map = L.map('mapid', {
  <!-- center: [51.1961, 13.3105], -->
  <!-- zoom: 15 -->
  center: [50.8, 14],
  zoom: 11
 });
 
 var basemaps = {
  OSM: L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
   minZoom: 4,
   maxZoom: 19,
   attribution: 'Map tiles by <a target="_blank" href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a> | Map data by <a target="_blank" href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" >OpenStreetMap</a>',
   subdomains: 'abcd'
  }),

  Boundaries: L.tileLayer.betterWms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
   layers: 'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land',
   transparent: true,
   format: 'image/png'
  }),
  
  FNP: L.tileLayer.betterWms("https://rz.ipm-gis.de/ags01/services/RAPIS/RAPIS_FNP/MapServer/WmsServer?", {
   layers: '1',
   format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
   attribution: 'WMS: <a target="_blank" href="https://www.geomis.sachsen.de/terraCatalog/Query/ShowCSWInfo.do?fileIdentifier=a57376e1-1de2-48f7-b125-0b43c5089d91">Flächennutzungsplan RAPIS</a>'
  })
 };

 L.control.layers(basemaps, {}, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

 basemaps.FNP.addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It does not work for the WMS 'FNP'. When I change the 'propertyName' to 'name' to test the request of the wms 'Boundaries' it works. So maybe some expressions are missing in the WMS 'FNP'? Both WMS are external and not published by myself.

Here are the sources/getCapabilities of both WMS:

- WMS 'FNP': https://rz.ipm-gis.de/ags01/services/RAPIS/RAPIS_FNP/MapServer/WmsServer?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS
- WMS 'Boundaries': https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

Do you have any idea why the instruction with the one wms works but not with the other one?

I would be very grateful for any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any idea why the instruction with the one wms works but not with the other one?

The service you refer to under the heading WMS 'Boundaries is not a WMS it's a WFS.  WFS do no support an operation called `GetFeatureInfo` only WMS support that operation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think all the features of the WMS 'FNP' are mandatory, so I cannot hide them. Interestingly the request of the WMS 'Boundaries' works, even it is a WFS.

Comment: The (any) WMS gives a map image of the underlying features that the service provider wants you to see by default (the default styling), if you want a different map image (with different features) you'll need to supply your own SLD, for the server to apply.

Comment: That it only goes this way, I thought so. Meanwhile I did a work-around. Thanks anyway for your fast reply!